# How to read from CPU0 SP register value of CPU1 on Cortex-A9?

Tags: arm, cpu-registers

I need to clear what cpu1 is doing during hang of cpu0.

I'm debugging very early stage of booting linux kernel, so no drivers or apps are started.

Comment: Is there a Linux on both cpus? You can't read this directly; use jtag or OS-provided debugging/profiling features to do this.

Comment: You need to provide more context if you want an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be solved via ETM feature of Cortex-A9.